# Where are most customers located?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, aggregate-functions

I have a datatable of customers similar to the following

```
CustID    InState
===================
1         0
2         0
3         1
```

Where InState = 0 corresponds to the customer being out-of-state, and Instate = 1 corresponds to the customer being in-state. I want to write a stored procedure to return "Out-of-State" if there are more out-of-state customers or return "In-State" if there are more in-state customers.

I have started just working with a basic query, and this is what I have:

```
SELECT
        COUNT(CASE WHEN InState = 0 THEN 1 END) as 'Out-of-State',
        COUNT(CASE WHEN InState = 1 THEN 1 END) as 'In-State'
FROM Customers
```

This gives me the counts for each category, but I only want the answer of the greater of the two. How could I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are pretty much there

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN COUNT(
                      CASE WHEN InState = 0 THEN 1 END) > 
                          COUNT(CASE WHEN InState = 1 THEN 1 END)
             THEN 'Out of State'
             ELSE 'In State'
         END GreaterClassification
  FROM Customers
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN InState = 0 THEN 1 END) as OutOfState,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN InState = 1 THEN 1 END) as InState,
CASE
 WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN InState = 0 THEN 1 END)- COUNT(CASE WHEN InState = 1 THEN 1 END)>0 THEN 'OUT OF STATE'
 WHEN  COUNT(CASE WHEN InState = 0 THEN 1 END)- COUNT(CASE WHEN InState = 1 THEN 1 END)<0 THEN 'IN STATE'
 ELSE 'DAMN THEY ARE EQUAL'
 END
 FROM Customers
```

Answer (score 0):

If `instate` only takes on the values of `0` and `1`, then use `sum()`:

```
select (case when sum(instate) > sum(1 - instate) then 'In State'
             when sum(instate) < sum(1 - instate) then 'Not In State'
             else 'Equal'
        end)
from customers;
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe something like this can help

```
declare @t table (custid int, instate int)
insert into @t values (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 1)

select case when t.instate = 1 then 'in the state' else 'not in the state' end as position
from   ( select top 1 count(instate) poscount, instate 
         from  @t
         group by instate
         order by 1 desc
       ) t
```

the result is `not in the state`